# Why does my WordPress ajax call response with a pagination parameter give me always the first page?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have an custom ajax call with a page parameter to recieve posts on the home.php template. It works but when I change the page parameter to a different one lets say something like this:

```
http://localhost/<my-wordpress-folder>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=getPaginatedProjects&page=2
```

it always returns the first page results, no  matter what number there is as the parameter.

I'm using the Sage 9 starter theme.

**Home.php controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Sober\Controller\Controller;
use WP_Query;

class Home extends Controller
{
  public function __construct() {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_getPaginatedProjects', function() {
      $response = $this->getPaginatedProjects();
      echo $response;
      wp_die();
    });
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getPaginatedProjects', function() {
      $response = $this->getPaginatedProjects();
      echo $response;
      wp_die();
    });
  }

  public function projectsQuery($page = 1) {
    $args = [
      'post_type'       => 'post',
      'posts_per_page'  => 5,
      'post_status'     => ['publish'],
      'paged'           => $page
    ];

    $projects = new WP_Query($args);
    return $projects;
  }

  protected function getPaginatedProjects() {
    $response = '';
    $page = strval($_POST['page']);
    $query = $this->projectsQuery($page);

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $response .= \App\template(locate_template('views/partials/single.blade.php'));
      }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $response = json_encode($response);
    return $response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$page = strval($_GET['page']);`

Comment: Yeah, lol, you're right! You can answer the question with it and I can sign it as a correct answer. May-be you can point out why POST was acting all wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

you asked for 1 page with 5 posts

try  $page -= 1;